# Get title and description dynamically by using an URL

Tags: java, url

I need to get title and description of a URL dynamically. What do I need to use in order to do this?

Take for example the following URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

I need to extract the tile of the URL and the description of it. Will you prefer jsoup extraction as below?

```
url.select("title");
```

If yes, how to extract description of the url?

Comment: What's the title and description of a URL? Do you mean the title of the HTML page located at the given URL? And if so, what is the description? Where can it be found?

Comment: yeah title of the html web page, the description of the html page from meta tag...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need a HTML parser like Jericho.

Take a look at this example:
http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/ExtractText.java

specially this two methods:

```
private static String getTitle(Source source) {
    Element titleElement=source.getFirstElement(HTMLElementName.TITLE);
    if (titleElement==null) return null;
    // TITLE element never contains other tags so just decode it collapsing whitespace:
    return CharacterReference.decodeCollapseWhiteSpace(titleElement.getContent());
}

private static String getMetaValue(Source source, String key) {
    for (int pos=0; pos<source.length();) {
        StartTag startTag=source.getNextStartTag(pos,"name",key,false);
        if (startTag==null) return null;
        if (startTag.getName()==HTMLElementName.META)
            return startTag.getAttributeValue("content"); // Attribute values are automatically decoded
        pos=startTag.getEnd();
    }
    return null;
}
```